# Update/ Create list item based on an existing entry in another list

Tags: workflow, insert-update-listitem

I have two lists : list A & list B. Both lists have identical schema and information. I have created a SharePoint 2010 designer workflow on list A ,which triggers when an item is updated in list A.

The workflow should basically check if the list item (in list A) being updated , exists in list B . If it exists, it should update it ( Call Update List Item action), else it should create a new list item in list B. Please suggest how can I check if the list item exists in list B?

Comment: Decide the primary key on both the lists and compare. Do you have one like that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, if in List B there is no item same as in List A, you would create new item and copy data from List A?

If that is the case, You could add additional column in List B, exp. listAID that would have ID number of ListA item. So, if that column is empty, create item in listB if it is not empty than update item in ListB.

Column listAID would fill on item creation.